# Can't upload new images on wordpress because i get the url of the previous domain

Tags: wordpress, path, upload, backend

Actually the title says enough. I have replaced my wordpress website from localhost to the domain. But now i can't upload new images. Because the image get automatically the url path from the old domain.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please update URL´s into Database, I recomend https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/.

Tutorial : https://www.valet.io/heres-a-quick-way-to-search-and-replace-your-database-after-migration/